# ¿porque android studio me obliga a convertir una variable en array? - Android Volley

Tags: android-studio, json, android-volley

Tengo una clase que se encarga de hacer una consulta mediante android volley a un web service que hize y declare una variable boleana que cuando el metodo `onResponse` de volley analiza la respuesta recibida en `JSON` y se encuentra que el web service le devolvio un TRUE pues la variable boleana debe modificar su valor a TRUE, pero android me marca error cuando quiero establecer el valor a TRUE(`b = true`) y me obliga a que lo convierta en array.

```
public boolean [] valido(Context context){
    final boolean[] b = new boolean[1];
    url = "http://localhost/api/acceso/iniciar_sesion/solicitar_validacion.php";
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("response");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String valor = data.getString("boolean");
                    if(valor.equals("true")){
                        b[0] = true;
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            if(error instanceof TimeoutError){
                String jsonError = "{'estado':'400','mensaje':'Comprueba tu conexión a internet.'}";
            }
        }
    }){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> credenciales = new HashMap<>();
            return credenciales;
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            credenciales.put("correo_electronico", correo_electronico);
            credenciales.put("contrasena", contrasena);
            return credenciales;
        }
    };
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
Toast.makeText(context, "return: "+b[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return b[0];
}
```

Ingresando los credenciales correctos el web service me devuelve un JSON con los siguientes valores:

```
D/response: {"response":[{"estado":"200","mensaje":"Password correcto","boolean":"true"}]}
```

Como ven devuelve la contraseña es correcta y en mi aplicacion android analizo la respuesta buscando el `key :  boolean` y preguntando en un `if` si es igual a `true`, si es asi quiero que la variable booleana se ponga en true pero no lo hace.

Tambien intente declarando la variable booleana fuera del metodo y ya no me pide que lo cambie a array pero surge otro problema, es de que si lo declaro fuera del metodo esta variable nunca modifica su valor, es decir: supuestamente esta linea de codigo deberia modificar el valor de la variable booleana: `b = true` pero nunca se modifica, me di cuenta que solo se modifica internamente osea dentro del metodo `onResponse` pero cuando sale del metodo nunca se modifico la variable. Alguien sabe porque pasa esto y como puedo solucionarlo?. Gracias.

Comment: Si tienes la variable declarada como `final` no va a cambiar nunca el valor, ya que las variables declaradas como `final` actuan como constantes y no como variables.

Comment: Si, pero yo no le puse como `final`, android studio automaticamente con el corrector lo declaro como final, cuando lo declaro fuera del metodo solo lo declaro como `private` y tampoco se modifica su valor. Yo que sepa `b = true` deberia modificar el valor de la variable desde cualquier metodo que sea llamado, pero no lo hace, nose porque. A menos el metodo `onResponse` no alcanze variables que se encuentre fuera de su metodo.

Comment: @Leonidas entiendo lo que comentas, y si se puede modificar su valor, aquí el problema es que no puedes asignar el valor true a el array pero si a si primer elemento que es b[0], por lo tanto lo debes de asignar de esta forma b[0] = true, agregué respuesta.

Comment: @Marc tienes razón en el caso de variables, pero en el caso de un array si se puede modificar el valor de sus elementos, saludos.

Comment: @Leonidas ya analice el problema, y se debe a que la petición es asincrona lo cual es lo ideal, esperar el resultado en un "callback", agregue una respuesta para explicar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La variable `b` es declarada como un arreglo de valores boleanos de un elemento:

```
 final boolean[] b = new boolean[1];
```

por esa razón no puedes asignar directamente el valor de `true` a la variable `b`

```
b = true
```

lo correcto es asignar el valor de `true` a el primer elemento del `array`.

```
b[0] = true
```

> ¿porque android studio me obliga a convertir una variable en array? -

Porque en este caso al definir como `final` el `array`, puedes modificar el valor de los elementos contenidos en el Array.

Si en lugar de un array, usaras una variable, su valor no podría ser modificado.

---

> pero surge otro problema, es de que si lo declaro fuera del metodo
>   esta variable nunca modifica su valor, es decir: supuestamente esta
>   linea de codigo deberia modificar el valor de la variable booleana: b
>   = true pero nunca se modifica, me di cuenta que solo se modifica internamente osea dentro del metodo onResponse pero cuando sale del
>   metodo nunca se modifico la variable.

**Al llamar el método la petición se realiza asincronicamente, por lo que puede tardar un poco en obtener la información y esto se realiza en el método `onResponse(String response)` o en el método `onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)` si es que ocurrió un error al realizar la petición.**

Por lo tanto son estos métodos donde puedes obtener el resultado de `b[0]`, realiza este cambio:

```
public void valido(Context context){
    final boolean[] b = new boolean[1];
    url = "http://localhost/api/acceso/iniciar_sesion/solicitar_validacion.php";
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("response");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String valor = data.getString("boolean");
                    if(valor.equals("true")){
                        b[0] = true;
                    }
                }

                //Imprime resultado.
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "return: "+b[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            if(error instanceof TimeoutError){
                String jsonError = "{'estado':'400','mensaje':'Comprueba tu conexión a internet.'}";
            }

            //Imprime resultado.
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ocurrio Error, return: "+b[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> credenciales = new HashMap<>();
            return credenciales;
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            credenciales.put("correo_electronico", "correo_electronico");
            credenciales.put("contrasena", "contrasena");
            return credenciales;
        }
    };
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    //Toast.makeText(context, "return: "+b[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //return b[0];
}
```

y llama tu método de esta forma:

```
 valido(getApplicationContext());
```

Si deseas realizar una petición sincrona, se puede realizar mediante Volley, pero el problema es que debes definir un tiempo máximo de espera, si transcurrido este tiempo no obtuviste respuesta, obtendrías un `TimeoutException`

https://www.appzonegroup.com/news/synchronous-and-asynchronous-volley/